# What would US employees think of having a notice period?

Tags: united-states, contracts, notice-period, at-will

[At first glance this might look unsuitable for SE since it is definitely an opinion-based question. However, in this case I'm not asking for opinions on the answer; I want opinions *as* the answer. So maybe it'll survive the deletion vote. ]

### TL;DR

**Would US employees see European-style reciprocal notice periods as a good or bad thing?**

### Details

I am an employer, just moved from the UK to the US, and preparing to hire here. I'm in tech -- electronics and s/w development. I'm hiring into jobs with base salaries for engineering staff starting at the low-to-mid $100Ks and on up into the mid $200Ks.

Now, I know that here in the US, the basis of employee/employer agreements is, or at least defaults to, at-will, and in particular that affects notice periods. That is, employees can ditch the job/employer at the drop of a hat, and, similarly, employers can kick employees out in the same way; in both cases, there is no requirement for advance warning, a.k.a. "notice". (Yes, I know there are other rules, such as those covering discrimination, that in practice modify/nullify/etc the theoretical at-will-ness, but in this context I'm looking at the default case. I am assuming a spherical job in a vacuum, as it were.) Now in practice, at least in the tech sector I'm part of, there does appear to be a customary notice giving from either party to the other, but it's only 2 weeks, and is, as I say, just a custom. So, here's my question:

How would the typical US tech employee (e.g. you, if appropriate), feel about a notice period that was both longer than 2 weeks; and required by contract, not just a voluntary custom? It might be 6 weeks, or maybe even as long as 3 months; let's pick 2 months as an example. In other words:

**How would you feel if you had a contract with your employer which meant that you had to give them two months notice prior to leaving your job, but also that they had to give you two months notice prior to letting you go?**

Comment: Question: what do you *as the employer* seek to get out of this? Is it just what you know or is there some other reason that you are seeking to have a non-standard (for the area you are in)?

Comment: I think this question should stay open but I am *compelled* to give you +1 just for "spherical job in a vacuum".

Comment: Depends on the individual, and I am neither a mind reader nor a fortune teller. If you want a valid answer, do a valid poll. Elsewhere.

Comment: Here is a good reason why it is better to get a local manager when moving into a new country. There are other customs which do not get translated between countries. You will run into further cultural challenges with sales and support.

Comment: Longer notice periods would require being compensated for that additional time. You should identify the reason you believe you need longer notice periods.  If it's about knowledge dump, there are solutions, like not having a single employee be charged with a critical piece of the business. The goal should be that, given an appropriate amount of notice, you are able to allow somebody to leave without any impact to your business.

Answer (score 4):

> How would you feel if you had a contract with your employer which meant that you had to give them two months notice prior to leaving your job, but also that they had to give you two months notice prior to letting you go?

I would feel that if I accept this contract, then when I look for the next job, it would be very difficult for me to convince the next employer to wait for 2 months before I can work for them.

As you already mentioned in your post, it is customary to have a 2 week notice in the US. So, most employers expect the new hires to be able to work in about 2 weeks (approximately) after accepting the job offer. Many employers plan their business schedules this way in the tech sector.

---

I would suggest that you may want to see if you can adjust your contract to allow employees to have a customary notice period of 2 weeks.

As you can see, many tech companies in the US don't have a big issue with this customary notice period of 2 weeks. **Their business work well. So, your business will also work well too.**

It will be much easier for you to hire employees if you follow the US standard when you are working in the US. Otherwise, you may miss out on many talented tech workers if you insist on a 2 month notice period.

(As they say it: "**When in Rome**,...")

Answer (score 2):

> How would you feel if you had a contract with ... two months notice ...?

I've done notice periods both in Europe and the US both as an employee and as a manager.

I VERY MUCH prefer the shorter US notice periods. In my experience being a lame duck for an extended period of time doesn't help anyone. Once the call has been made, its best to just get it over with as quickly as possible.

I don't buy the argument that longer notice periods gives the employer more time to hire a replacement. The problem is most people you would want to hire sit on an equally long notice period at their current gig. So it just drags out the process with no real benefit. So yes, you have two months to find a replacement, but no, the replacement cannot start next week since they ALSO have to serve a two months notice period.

Personally I would not sign such a contract in the US because it would make me mostly unemployable. Every potential employer expects you to be available within a few weeks and they are unlikely to wait for two months especially if comparable candidates are available quicker.

My last notice period in Europe was a ridiculous 6 months. The only way to get out, was my employer graciously agreeing to a shorter notice (Aufloesungsvertrag) . I don't ever want to be in this position again.

Which brings me to the final point: You can't really force an employee to do great work when they fundamentally don't want to be there. Most departing employees are good sports about this but the longer the notice period, the harder this gets. If they actually leave early: what will you do? You can't forcibly drag them back into the office, so your only remedy is to sue for damages. That's not going to make you popular with your employee base, you would have to quantify actual damages, and I doubt most courts will look sympathetically at something like this.